# WP Adding extra title in main navigation?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

So I've added a menu to my custom WP theme, which all is good with. However, when I refresh the page, an extra blank title in the menu shows up. Is there a fix to this? Did I do something wrong?

Here is a image of what I am talking about: 
http://oi46.tinypic.com/17txc8.jpg

```
<div id="navbar">
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => 'Primary Menu', 'container' => false,'menu_id' => 'main-nav','depth'=>'2')); ?>
        <div id="login" >
    <?php if (!(current_user_can('level_0'))){ ?>               
    <form name="loginform" id="loginform" action="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-login.php" method="post">

        <input value="Username" class="input" type="text" tabindex="10" name="log" id="user_login" style="padding-left: 2px;" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Username') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Username';}" />
        <input value="Password" class="input" type="password" tabindex="20" name="pwd" id="user_pass" style="padding-left: 2px;" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Password') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Password';}" />
        <input name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit" tabindex="100" value=" " type="submit" class="loginbutton" >
        <input name="redirect_to" value="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>" type="hidden">
        <input name="testcookie" value="1" type="hidden">

</form>
            <a class="helpbutton" href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword"></a>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <ul class="admin_box">
                <li><a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/wp-admin/">Dashboard</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/wp-admin/post-new.php">Write New Post</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/forums">Forums</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url('$index.php'); ?>">Log out</a></li>
        </ul>
    <?php }?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I don't see any extra title. Is it the `About` in the bottom-left which seems to be broken off of the navbar?

Comment: yeah, well what it does is add a <a></a> to the very beginning of the navbar which is why there is a blank space before Home. When it does this, yes it pushes it below the actual navbar.

Comment: <a class="helpbutton" href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword"></a>

I assume this isnt the offender? It has no content.

Comment: What should it be then? Doesn't that call for "http://www.siteurl.com/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword?

Answer (score 0):

You can override this through CSS.

Just add a `margin-left:-30px;` to the `#navbar`. This will move your entire navbar to the left and get space for about menu.

Adjust the `margin-left` value to get the correct position.